# Number of simplices contained in a convex body

Tags: discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry

I am interested in the following question:

Given a convex body $K$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and an $\epsilon>0$ small enough, how many $d$-simplices $\{D_i\}_{i=1}^m\subset K$ do we need at least so that the volume of $K\setminus \cup_{i=1}^m D_i$ is at most $\epsilon\mathrm{vol}(K)$?

Similar question has been considered for approximating polytopes with given number of vertices or faces, but I am not aware of any result of this kind. Any comment shall be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't you need to stipulate that $D_i \subseteq K$? Otherwise one simplex suffices: Take $D_1$ to just completely cover $K$, and then shrink $D_1$ a little.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Yes, of course $D_i$ is contained in $K$.